# How to plot in python using Legend as a checkbox?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, jupyter, bokeh, data-analysis

I have been trying to plot a graph which has a dataframe having 3 columns . One is the "Hour", Second is the "amount" in Rupees and the third consist of "machine codes". I need to analyze the amount of transaction a machine does on an hourly basis. There are total 67 unique machine codes.
Kindy check here the data sample [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gjKl.jpg)

These are the Libraries i have been using

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_notebook()
p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = sl['Hour']
y = sl['amount']
```

Now I have appended a list labels[] with all the machine codes

```
labels = []
active1 = []
for s in sl['machinecode'].unique():
    labels.append(s)
    active1.append(0)
```

I basically want to create checkboxes for all those machine codes , a user when check any machine code , a graph gets plotted . if a user again checks another machine code , the line of that machine code gets appended into a graph so that I could compare between machines.

```
j =0
for i in sl['machinecode'].unique():

      l = p.line(x, y, color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line:" , **props)
      j=j+1


checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=labels,
                     active=active1, width=100)
checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l=l, checkbox=checkbox),
                          code="""
  l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
  l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
  l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
  """"")

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

The above code is showing something really different [kindly check here what the graph is actually showing , it is plotting for every machine with a single color , checkboxes does not command the graph actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqjwP.jpg)